# ASP.NET object visibility

Tags: asp.net, visibility

I have a webform with a button and a textbox.
I want to set the textbox, in design time to Visible = false, and then in the onclick event of the button
in the client side using javascript, I want to set the visibility of the button back to true.
The problem is that I get a message saying that the object does not exist.

Any idea how to solve this?

TY

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Server-side visibility prevents the control rendering to the browser altogether. Rather than hiding the textbox using `Visible="false"`, hide it using CSS - `visibility:hidden`.